# Memory leak ,android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$DeathMonitor GREF has increased to 2001

Tags: android, html

when quickly opening and closing Bluetooth over 100 times, this problem will occurs.
and my framework also add  [private boolean mForgotten] and its hanlder;
but this problem is still exist.

03-23 20:31:20.759 D/dalvikvm(  369): GREF has increased to 2001
03-23 20:31:20.759 W/dalvikvm(  369): JNI global reference table (0x1b2ccb8) dump:
.
.
.
android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$DeathMonitor (643 unique instances)
.
.
. 
my testing code is :

```
 while (true) {
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
            atempToConnectNum++;
            if (atempToConnectNum == 1500) {
                break;
            }
        } else {
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to open and close bluetooth so many times so quickly?

Comment: hi  xxpor . first thanks, you see this problem. In order to press test can pass . actual this problem is exists.

Comment: I think this problem is that so many times connect ibinder .but I don't know where it occurs.